# Telegraf session for unique user?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm building a  wallet bot and I was wondering how can I initiate a session for an unique user. For example, in this session I would need an object containing the unique user identifier, the public key and secret key so they can access this after initiating the bot.

I was thinking in something like this:

```
var myWallet = (ctx) =>{
return{
  user: ctx.from.id,
  publicKey: wallet.public,
  secretKey: wallet.secret

}
}

bot.command('/myWallet', (ctx)=>{
   ctx.reply(myWallet.user);
   ctx.reply(myWallet.publicKey);
   ctx.reply(myWallet.secretKey);
})
```

But when I type /myWallet on my bot nothing happens, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Might be a bit late but for sessions you can use [Telegrafs inbuild session management](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=session). Here an example:

```
const session = require('telegraf/session')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
bot.use(session())
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
    ctx.session.counter = ctx.session.counter || 0
    ctx.session.counter++
    return ctx.reply(`Message counter:${ctx.session.counter}`)
})
```

Basically it just works like above example. You intitiate a session (`bot.use(session());`) then when a user writes you use the context of the returned message (`ctx`) in which all user data is stored (username, id, message, etc) and calling the session from that (`ctx.session`). In there you store your regular variable data. Now normal sesions are active until the bot shuts down. When you want persistent sessions just import an 3rd-party session manager as written in the docs.

So to sum that up:

```
const session = require('telegraf/session') // import session addon
ctx.session.walletData = 'some data' // store data in session
console.log(ctx.session.walletData) // show data
```

Comment: For which version?